# Is there Hot Reload with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, hot-reload

Im researching Swift features and have the Question if there is a Hot Reload Feature or something similar like "instant run".

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/
On this Page they say:

"Xcode includes intuitive design tools that make building interfaces with SwiftUI as easy as dragging and dropping. As you work in the design canvas, everything you edit is completely in sync with the code in the adjoining editor. **Code is instantly visible as a preview as you type, and any change you make to that preview immediately appears in your code. Xcode recompiles your changes instantly and inserts them into a running version of your app — visible, and editable at all times**."

My question to that is if this is only true for UI-Development with Swift but doesnt work with thie normal Logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only a feature of Previews, but if you select the "run" button in the preview toolbar, it will run a lot of arbitrary code in ways that are very similar to hot reloading.

Comment: Do you have a link where this is described or any keywords i could search for?

I cant find anything in the official docs or elsewhere

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/233/

Answer (score 7):

To your question of processing normal logic and not just a preview of the UI components, as of today Apple does not provide that feature however there is an open source project that seeks to accomplish what you're looking for:

https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Inject

Comment: this is the answer. here's the example app with swiftui usage: https://github.com/MarcoEidinger/InjectSwiftUIExample

Answer (score 2):

Not really... not like in flutter, when your code runs in true vm... and allows hot reloads, there is some kind of preview, but you will have to write some code and update env params. But it not nearlly as good as under real vm env.

Answer (score 1):

> My question to that is if this is only true for UI-Development with Swift but doesnt work with thie normal Logic.

Are you looking for [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)? If so, you might be looking for [Swift Playground](https://developer.apple.com/swift-playgrounds/). Xcode also has it's own playground system, but I'm having trouble finding good supporting documentations.